# xcode4: Linker error: Directory not found for option

Tags: macos, xcode4, build, linker

I'm getting this error for my profile build (debug build was OK).

```
{Directory not found for option '-L../../../Mac/Profile/lib [full path of that directory]

Library not found for -lMyLib}
```

When I check the path, the directory exists and the lib file libMyLib.a exists as well.
My library search path for the Profile build includes that directory $(SRCROOT)/../../../Mac/Profile/lib. I also made sure that the library was built under profile setting.

This only happens with profile build.

I'd really love to have some help although it may well be a no-brainer question.

Thank you!

**EDIT: Found the solution myself**
Solved the problem: In my linker path, there were two directory entries. The second one was surrounded by double quotes while the first one wasn't. Xcode4 seems to have concatenated them into a single directory entry and apparently that was garbage. After I removed the quotation marks, the linker error was gone.

Answer (score 103):

Go to "Get Info" on the target. Click the "Build Settings" tab (i'm using Xcode4), and scroll down to "Search Paths", Where You delete all the values in "Library Search Paths".

Comment: Even though its over 2 years old I wanted to say thank you: Finally got rid of my problem :)

Comment: My "Library Search Paths" field was already empty but my problem was similar: there were extra values in the "Framework Search Paths" field that needed to be removed.

Comment: What worked for me was deleting everything under Library Search Paths and Framework Search Paths changing both to "." and recursive.

Answer (score 54):

There are two errors that people seem to have confused

If it is a "directory not found for option '**-L**/..."
That means it's a Library Error, and you might want to try:

- Click on your project (targets)
- Click on Build Settings
- Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths

If it is a "directory not found for option '**-F**/..."
That means it's a Framework Error, and you might want to try:

- Click on your project (targets)
- Click on Build Settings
- Under `Framework Search Paths`, delete the paths

This might happen when you move referenced files around or change the project folder name.

Answer (score 1):

It was similar as above in the Library Search Paths. I found that one of my paths was missing quotes around it...

```
// Old path
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Google Analytics

// New path
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Google Analytics"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error in seemingly a completely different scenario from those answers above. Hopefully some people will do what I did and find this useful even if it is a rare occurence.

I managed to get this error after having just added a new viewController to my project. As normal I added a tableview and constrained it then added and linked the delegate and datasource. I also created a property.

The weird thing that I then noticed was that as soon as I finished creating the property it was immediately linked, as if I had linked it, but before I linked it. When I clicked on the xib file and checked the links it wasn't in fact linked to the table view.

[image]

(This link appeared automatically without me needing to create it myself)

I don't know why this happened. I deleted the file and remade it with the same name but it just happened again. Giving me this error above.

The way I solved it was to create a new file, different name, and added and created the links in a different order checking at each step that this hadn't occurred. After doing this no linked created themselves and it worked.

TL DR: If you are getting this error and have recently added  new view controller then check if deleting it works and if so they remake it being careful about any automatic links.