# I am trying to add MDCCard in Swift to get Material Card View using Material Components. Error : No such module 'MaterialComponents.MaterialCards'

Tags: ios, swift, material-components-ios

I am following this tutorial - https://material.io/components/ios/catalog/cards/

It tells me to add pod 'MaterialComponents/Cards' in addition to pod 'MaterialComponents'

On running pod install, I get the following error -

> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
>   "MaterialComponents/Cards"

Without that, XCode cannot find the MaterialCards component -

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialCards
```

gives the error -

> No such module 'MaterialComponents.MaterialCards'

Comment: Did you try `pod repo update` and them `pod install`

Comment: Of course! Should have been the first thing I should have done. Unfortunately, after updating I am now getting another error - Specs satisfying the `MaterialComponents/Cards` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target. My minimum deployment target is already 11.1 - which is currently the highest possible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this can solve you problem, I found it when I was using a diff modules and xCode didn't find my modules

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63673139/8365583

Answer (score 0):

You can go in XCWorkspace's pod section and there would be a ruby file which you be your pod file. Then pop out your right pane and then add to your target membership.   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb7DF.png)

Answer (score -1):

I solved by uninstall Material components  (remove from Pod file 'MaterialComponents' row ) and reinstall again by adding into Pod file first 'MaterialComponents' and after 'MaterialComponents/Cards'. After installation, i built the project and now I can see MaterialComponenets.MaterialCards