# framework not found SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swifty-json

I'm getting that "framework not found SwiftyJSON" error after pod update. I have tried many clean build folder and project. But It still stays in there. What should I do?

my pod file

```html
platform :ios, ‘9.0’
use_frameworks!

target ‘QRContact’ do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.1'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'Firebase'
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Framework not found' in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687105/framework-not-found-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Project Navigator`, in folder `Pods`,

Remove Pods.framework in:

Folder named Pods
Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i used below fix to resolve this issue

Step1, Select `SwiftyJSON` pod target and go to build settings.
Step2, Under `Architecture` section select 'Standard Architecture'

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having the same problem, make sure that you are opening the  xcworkspace (generated after installing the pod package) file in you app folder and not xcodeproj file.